# How can I convert multiple rows into set of columns?

Tags: excel, excel-2010

How can I convert multiple rows into one column?

Below is my CSV file data. Name, Location,Mobile,Email repeat multiple times. Sometimes, Location can be missed and mobile may have multiple entries.

```
Name,XXX
Location,Berlin
Mobile,999xxxxx00
Email, xxx@xmail.com
Name, YYYYY
Location,Paris
Mobile,999xxxxx33,999xxxxx55
Email, yyyy@xmail.com,yyyy@gmail.com
Name, ZZZZZ
Mobile,989xxxxx65,899xxxxx60,799xxxxx89.899xxx6590,889xxxxx60
Email, zzzz@xmail.com
Name,PPPP
Location,Spain
Mobile,999xxxxx77,
Email,pppp@xmail.com
Name,QQQQQ
Location,London
Mobile,999xxxxx65,999xxxxx60,999xxxxx89.999xxx6590
Email,qqqq@xmail.com
```

I want this data should be fit like below:

```
Name   |   Location   |   Mobile     |   E-mail
----------------------------------------------------
XXXx        Berlin      999xxxxx00    xxx@xmail.com
YYYYY       Paris       999xxxxx33    yyyy@xmail.com
YYYYY                   999xxxxx55    yyyy@gmail.com
ZZZZZ                   989xxxxx65    zzzz@xmail.com
                        899xxxxx60    
                        799xxxxx89    
                        899xxx6590    
                        889xxxxx60    
PPPP        Spain       999xxxxx77    pppp@xmail.com
QQQQQ       London      999xxxxx65    qqqq@xmail.com
                        999xxxxx60    
                        999xxxxx89    
                        999xxx6590
```

It would be better, if name is displayed repeatedly instead of making it empty.

Comment: I think your solution lies in using VBA.

Answer (score 0):

I would do `Text to Columns` (Data > Text to Columns).

On that window, choose `Delimited` then click `Next` and make sure you just have `Comma` selected, then click `Finish`.

After you do that, copy the data then right-click the first cell where you want to paste the data, and pick `Transpose`.

That should give you the desired outcome.